# Git LFS delete files older than a commit

Tags: git, delete-file, git-lfs

My LFS storage is unfortunately full. Is there any solution for deleting files in LFS? Is there possible to delete files which are older than a specific commit?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is only possible if you filter your branch and decouple an existing branch.

https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-git-large-file-storage/

Or you copy your data to a new Git-Repo and delete files you don't need. If you have a reference in you Git history you can't delete a file.